# GIDSignIn returns "Keychain error"

Tags: ios8, google-plus, single-sign-on, google-oauth

I'm implementing sign in with Google plus. The implementation is basically copied from examples from [Developer Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in).
When I login for the first time all works fine. But if I then logout using

```
 [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signOut];
```

next time I login in I get the

```
Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-2 "keychain error"
```

Please advice what can be done in this situation. 
Thanks

Comment: Anyone able to fix this issue?

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Comment: @Jan no, i'm still seeing this issue.

Comment: Make sure App has Keychain Access Capability: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38818137/4004429

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm having the same issue here. After doing some tests, i've noticed that if i run my app without the debugger (Build, stop, run app) everything works as expected...try it

Answer (score 2):

Probably a long shot, but try calling `disconnect` on the sharedInstance?

```
- (void)signOut {
    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] disconnect];
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Already doing this in my code, still same issue…

Comment: Yes, same here... this doesn't help the issue

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are trying to solve is connected with keychain access. To fix issue you simply should go to Target->Capabilities and enable keychain sharing

Comment: This is a reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38812761/gidsignin-keychain-error-ios-10-xcode-8/38818137#38818137

Comment: Keychain was enabled already in Capabilities. Please, see the gafos' answer.