# Xamarin Auth Store Keychain not working after ios10 upgrade

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.auth

I'm using Xamarin.Auth (https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth/) to store my credentials, as I've always done.

```cs
var accountStore = AccountStore.Create ();
foreach (var account in  accountStore.FindAccountsForService("myAppName"))
    accountStore.Delete (account, "myAppName");

AccountStore.Create().Save(acc, "myAppName");
```

After the upgrade to iOS 10 I get this error storing credentials:

```
"Could not save account to KeyChain: -34018"

at Xamarin.Auth.KeyChainAccountStore.Save (Xamarin.Auth.Account account,System.String serviceId) [0x000b2] in <402cf9b3716845b3bdddef581cb33a3e>:0
```

Latest version installed 1.2.3.1
The problem seems to persist only on the SIMULATOR

Comment: Here is an easy [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43547670/730807) just **Enable Keychain** in capabilities thats all

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I was digging through the link **Pat** sent in the comment:
[bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43514](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43514)

And found a helpfull comment by **Pavel Sich**, he said:

> Just make sure you enable the keychain access in Entitlements and select the entitlements for Simulator (Debug) builds too. By default this is not set.

In my xamarin solution, I double clicked the .IOS project to open the options pane, selected *IOS Bundle Signing* and changed the *Platform* select box from "iPhone" to "iPhoneSimulator", then set the field *Custom Entitlements* to my Entitlements.plist. Now it's working fine for me.

Just a note, this is after editing the Entitlement.plist as suggested by **Thibault D.** in the previous answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I where having trouble with the Facebook iOS SDK on iOS 10 using XCode 8. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689631/how-to-use-facebook-ios-sdk-on-ios-10/38799196#38799196 And you solved it. :)

Comment: Sir, I own you my full gratitude. Thank you very much, it works like a charm!

Comment: Same solution with Visual Studio and Xamarin

Comment: Just to note, that you should use full app id with prefix created by apple. You may add it as "$(AppIdentifierPrefix)yourAppId" and it will do the trick http://stackoverflow.com/a/17624005/3507404

Comment: Haha thanks, that's weird. I just hit this issue myself today and found this answer and saw my name in it (I had completely forgotten about this issue and my answer).

Comment: And as explained here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60617#180567 it's enough that you have an empty Entitlements file. You don't need to enable shared keychain in the entitlements file.

Comment: I tried the same steps in Xamarin studio but still same issue.

Comment: Adding the custom entitlements to the simulator is what worked for me as well. I didn't need to manually `<key>keychain-access-groups</key>` to the Entitlements.plist.

Comment: Not Working for me

Answer (score 14):

According to [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60617#180567) it's enough that you add an empty entitlements file in you bundle singing configuration:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|iPhoneSimulator' ">
  ...
  <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Empty `Entitlements.plist` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I Added this to my Entitlements.plist... Same problem! <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
 <array>
  <string>MyAppID</string>
 </array>

Comment: Does not work for me either.  Been watching this bug...  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43514

Comment: I've edited my answer with instructions regarding how you get the Entitlements file to get used by the build configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Set Custom Entitlements in ios project settings
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when you work on `IphoneSimulator` even you enabled `KeyChain` in `Entitlements.plist`, it still doesnt work and throws this exception. Because Xamarin doesnt seem to have `CodesignEntitlements` sets for IphoneSimulator configuration as default although it has for `Iphone`  configurations. You have to open your `IOS.csproj` file and manually add this line

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|iPhoneSimulator' ">

  <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
</PropertyGroup>
```