# MonoTouch SecKeyChain.Add returning -34018 instead of readable value

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, keychain, ios10

I have updated my simulator to iOS 10 and after a fresh new install of my app, i'm trying to save information in the keychain and it now crash with StatusCode -34018...

```
        SecStatusCode returnCode;

        var match = SecKeyChain.QueryAsRecord(query, out returnCode);
        if (match == null)
        {
            var s = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
            {
                Label = DEVICE_IDENTIFIER_LABEL,
                Description = DEVICE_DESCRIPTION,
                ValueData = NSData.FromString(uuid),
                Accessible = SecAccessible.Always
            };

            returnCode = SecKeyChain.Add(s);
        }
```

returnCode is returning -34018... I have no idea what's that mean and found nothing about it. I found those related code in the Assembly Browser though:

```
public enum SecStatusCode
{
    Success,
    Unimplemented = -4,
    IO = -36,
    OpWr = -49,
    Param = -50,
    Allocate = -108,
    UserCanceled = -128,
    BadReq = -909,
    InternalComponent = -2070,
    NotAvailable = -25291,
    ReadOnly = -25292,
    AuthFailed = -25293,
    NoSuchKeyChain = -25294,
    InvalidKeyChain = -25295,
    DuplicateKeyChain = -25296,
    DuplicateItem = -25299,
    ItemNotFound = -25300,
    InteractionNotAllowed = -25308,
    Decode = -26275,
    VerifyFailed = -67808
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456471/secitemadd-always-returns-error-34018-in-xcode-8-in-ios-10-simulator

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487368/xamarin-auth-store-keychain-not-working-after-ios10-upgrade