# Crashing at AccountStore.Create ().Save (e.Account, ");

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

In the Xamarin.Forms example ToDoAwsAuth at

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/authentication/oauth/

After successful login, in aOnAuthenticationCompleted event, the application is crashing when trying to save to Xamarin.Auth at

```
AccountStore.Create ().Save (e.Account, "ToDoList");
```

The error says not able to say to keychain

Looking forward for help.

Comment: Hey OP, if you still alive, what is the actual error message? What do you mean by `not able to say to keychain`.

Answer (score 8):

See if you have a file called **Entitlements.plist** if so click on it and check **Enable Keychain**

[image: Capabilities]

or

create a new file names **Entitlements.plist** with the following content then drag and drop it on your project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>your bundle id</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

- **Right click** on your project
- Choose **Options**
- Choose **iOS Bundle Signing**
- Choose **Entitlements.plist**

[image: xam studio options]

Thats all then it should be fine !

Comment: Make sure you select iPhone Simulator. For me it shows an Entitlements.plist under Active configuration in VS2017 but not if you explicitly selects Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug in Xamarin.Auth as per this

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues/128

Comment: Not only -  there are several issues under the same code that iOS returns.

- problems with iOS10 simulator and
- bug in Xamarin.Auth that prevented storing if the screen is locked

Answer (score 1):

Just add empty Entitlements.plist to your iOS app project.

Select(iOS App Project) /+ File /+ New File /+ iOS /+ Entitlements.plist

Note: this seems to be result of one bug in Xamarin.Auth and Apple's changes in iOS 10 SDK (some report bug in simulator).

Xamarin.Auth fix will be released within next few hours (CI servers) in nuget version 1.3.3-alpha-01

Similar error (bug in Xamarin.Auth) can happen if the authentication is performed while the screen is being locked. PR 80

Related:

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues/128
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=43514

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/pull/80