# Why it's not possible to save something in Keychain on iOS simulator?

Tags: keychain

No matter what access group I use, I'm not able to save data in Keychain on iOS simulator. With real device everything works fine.
Is it possible at all to work with Keychain on simulator?

BTW I use SwiftKeychainWrapper library

Comment: found any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem in my Xamarin project and I know this is a solution for Xcode based iOS project also

Found out that **Entitlements.plist** in missing

Basically we have to check **Enable Keychain** in Capabilities

[image: Capabilities]

If you are interested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43547670/730807) is how I got my problem solved in Xam studio