# Xamarin - Adding custom entitlements.plist causes build error MessagingRemoteException

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, entitlements

I am running on visual studio 2015. I have linked my visual studio to the mac. iOS 10.1. Xamarin forms 2.3.2.127 in visual studio.

I'm currently trying to fix a bug that was mentioned at [Xamarin Auth Store Keychain not working after ios10 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487368/xamarin-auth-store-keychain-not-working-after-ios10-upgrade). When I try and add a custom entitlement as mentioned in the iOS Bundle Signing section, I now run into a build problem which states the message below. Soon as I remove the custom entitlement, it will build fine.

*MessagingRemoteException: An error occured on client Build42164 while executing a reply for topic xvs/Build/4.2.1.64/execute-task/Snap.iOS/9bfff3a%2FDetectSigningIdentity
DirectoryNotFoundException: Directory [DIRECTORY] not found.*

Any ideas?

Comment: Sometimes clean/rebuild can solve those kinds of problems.

Comment: Tried that many times, no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was caused as I needed to sign up to an apple developer account. Once I did that, I created an App ID and created a provision in the apple developer portal. The identifier in the info.plist must match the same name as you setup in the portal. Then I went into xcode > Preferences > Added my account > Downloaded the provision profile. (this will be the same as you setup in the apple portal). Under IOS Bundle signing, ensure you choose your provisioning profile.